# Is there a way to disable right horizontal scrolling, but allow left horizontal scrolling?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to disable right horizontal scrolling, but allow left horizontal scrolling?

```
let touches = []
window.addEventListener('touchmove', event => {
  event.preventDefault()
}, false)

window.addEventListener('touchstart', event => {
  touches[0] = event.touches[0].pageX
}, false)

window.addEventListener('touchend', event => {
  touches[1] = event.changedTouches[0].pageX
}, false)
```

It seems you would have to `preventDefault()` on the `touchmove` event.

Comment: You could compare the positions you have saved in `touches` to determine if it was a left or a right scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

touchmove returns list of touche

1. touchmove event object has list of touches
2. get the first touch, and prevent default in all cases.
3. on move compare new x value with old x value
4. if nx - ox > 0 then move manually.

**Example:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWQJvx

```
var old_x = null;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  old_x = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
}, false); 

document.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(e) {
  old_x = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
}, false); 


document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  if (touch.clientX - old_x < 0 ) {
    document.body.scrollLeft +=  old_x - touch.clientX;
  }
  old_x = touch.clientX;
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;   
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: I am only able to implement this on `touchend`.  Can you provide an example?